# Solr - Searching Multiple Fields

Tags: search, solr, global

I'm trying to allow a global search across all fields defined in my solr schema.xml. I have the following field:

```
     <field name="catchall" 
       type="text_en_splitting" 
       stored="true" 
       indexed="true"
       multiValued="true" />
```

Then, I have:

```
 <copyField source="*" dest="catchall"/>
 <defaultSearchField>catchall</defaultSearchField>
```

However, when I search without specifying a field, it only searches this field:

```
 <field name="text" type="text_en_splitting" multiValued="false"/>
```

Is my configuration missing something to search across all fields? Here's an example of the field that is not being included in the default search:

```
<field name="summary" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I figured out the issue. Apparently with Solr 3.6.1, the default search field is specified in solrconfig.xml rather than in the schema.xml. In solrconfig.xml, I changed the  element value from text to catchall.

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">catchall</str>
 </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```